# How to perform a GET request to cross origin using vertx?

Tags: java, vert.x, http-get

I am using `vert.x` with `JAVA` on the server side.
when client goes to `http://localhost:8080/hello`,  I want the browser to go to `"google.com"`.
I get an error when executing the `GET` request

```
    router.route("/hello").handler(routingContext -> {
        String url = "google.com";
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx, new WebClientOptions().setSsl(true).setTrustAll(true).setDefaultPort(8080).setKeepAlive(true).setDefaultHost(url));
        client.get(url).as(BodyCodec.string()).send(ar -> {
            if(ar.succeeded()) {
                HttpResponse<String> response = ar.result();
                System.out.println("Got HTTP response body");
                System.out.println(response.body().toString());                 
            }
            else {
                ar.cause().printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    });
```

Error:

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: google.com/172.217.16.142:8080
```

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement? For what I see, you're sending a request to your own server with path `google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's sort out some things.

First, cross origin is relevant to browsers. You're issuing a server-to-server request, so it's not relevant here.

Second, I hope you don't actually need to issue request to `google.com`, as Google actually tries to stop others to use its search page that way.

Third, you're using your `url` argument twice. Once when you set your default host, and second time when issuing a `get()` request. Then you also set port to `8080`, which `google.com` doesn't expose last time I checked.

Which produces something like:

`https://google.com:8080/google.com`

To receive response that makes a little bit more sense, you can try this code (I removed the routing part):

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    String url = "api.openweathermap.org";
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx, new WebClientOptions().setDefaultPort(80).setDefaultHost(url));
    client.get("/data/2.5/weather?q=london,uk&units=metric&appid=e38f373567e83d2ba1b6928384435689").as(BodyCodec.string()).send(ar -> {
        if(ar.succeeded()) {
            HttpResponse<String> response = ar.result();
            System.out.println("Got HTTP response body");
            System.out.println(response.body());
        }
        else {
            ar.cause().printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! It works with google but actually I wanted to perform a GET request to another URL which is a weather API. The code you wrote works for google but not for this weather API URL:
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london,uk&units=metric&appid=e38f373567e83d2ba1b6928384435689

Comment: I've updated my original answer with your example, and checked that it works. Enjoy :)